# Почему в слове "зонтик" -ик — это суффикс, хотя оно пришло в язык в полной форме?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, морфемика, историческое-словообразование

Викисловарь:

Корень: -зонт-; суффикс: -ик [Тихонов, 1996].

Происходит от нидерл. zonnedek «навес от солнца». Zondek — сложение zon «солнце» и dek «покрышка». Первонач. слово морск. языка. Русск. зонт, зо́нтик; стар. зондек «тент, полотно или парусина, растягиваемые над палубой (для защиты от солнца и дождя)», Уст. морск. 1720 г. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

Прочитал здесь, что версия происхождения может быть не точной. Тем не менее, если принять её как верную, как исторически получилось, что суффикс "откололся" от корня? Возможно, по обратному принципу (пришло полностью, затем использовали краткую форму, а после вернулись к начальной и приняли её как уменьшительную)?

Comment: обрубили корень, кто ж знал, похоже ведь на суффикс.  По идеи все словари пишут, что это заимствование зондек. deka < нем. Decke «покрышка, верхняя доска» она же дека. Так что солндек должен быть, но это вопросы к переводчикам.

Comment: Раз есть уменьшительно-ласкательное значение, то есть и суффикс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**С диахронной точки зрения** слово ЗОНТ образовано от ЗОНТИК, заимствованного из нидерландского.

Однако **с позиций синхронной точки зрения история образования этих слов не имеет никакого значения:** в современном русском языке есть лексема ЗОНТ, от которой синхронно образуется производное ЗОНТИК — точно так же, как СТОЛИК образуется от СТОЛ, ДОМИК – от ДОМ, НОСИК – от НОС и т.д. в тысячах похожих случаев.

Из книги [Николай Перцов, Игорь Мельчук. Курс общей морфологии. Том 1]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А примерно когда вместо "зонтик" в нейтральной речи стали использовать "зонт"? Также когда "зонт", а не "зонтик" появилось в словаре? В текстах Лермонтова пока еще присутствует "зонтик", как и в словарях того времени. Но это было почти 200 лет назад. А как там все дальше развивалось, вот что интересно. Вот это можно бы считать новой информацией в этой теме.

Answer (score 1):

Зонт (зонти́к). Как вы думаете, которое из этих двух слов — «отец», которое — «дитя»? Что произведено от чего: «зонтик» от «зонт» или наоборот? На первый взгляд, в чем тут сомневаться: «фунтик» — от «фунт», «фронтик» — от «фронт»; очевидно, и «зонтик» — от «зонт»…

Представьте себе, как раз наоборот! В XVIII веке мы позаимствовали из голландского языка термин «зо́ндэк» («навес, тент над палубой»), образованный из «зон» — «солнце», «дэк» — «покрышка». Из него у нас возникло «зонтик», оказавшееся похожим на наши уменьшительные формы «бантик», «франтик» совершенно случайно. Но язык проделал обратную обычной работу: от слова «зонтик» он произвел никогда не существовавшую ни в каких языках, так сказать «уболыпительную» форму «зонт».

Получился некоторый этимологический «повертон».

[Этимологическом онлайн-словарь Успенского Л. В.](https://lexicography.online/etymology/uspensky/%D0%B7/%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82)